# calculate average hours in power bi

Tags: dax

Good afternoon, could someone help me get the average number of hours? I've been trying but I can't do it right. These are the columns I have. ID_Ticket, number, created, update, close. These columns are date and time data types. These tickets are created in a month and can be be resolved in another month or year, also only take working hours which are 8 hours and Saturday 4 hours

I tried several formulas in dax but since I hardly know much about power bi I don't know what to do right

Answer (score 0):

DIVIDE(AVERAGEX('FactTable',DATEDIFF([Created],[Close],minute)),60)

(Of course the interval is the last argument in the DAX expression when it's the first one in T-SQL)